# how to only get the digit after dollar sign

Tags: php, regex

if the $str is like `sokewe(letter) $ 10,00  seqee(letter)`  how to only get the digit after dollar sign  ?

eg `sokewe(letter) $ 10,00  seqee(letter)`  `sokewe(letter) $ 1000  seqee(letter)`

```
<?php

if (preg_match('/\$\s[0-9]/',$str)) {
  // echo'has $ digit';
  $currency = '$';
  $digit = ..
} else if (preg_match('/\$[0-9]/',$str)) {
  // echo'has $digit';
  $currency = '$';
}

if (preg_match('/\£\s[0-9]/',$str)) {
  // echo'has £ digit';
  $currency = '£';
} else if (preg_match('/\£[0-9]/',$str)) {
  // echo'has £digit';
  $currency = '£';
}

if (preg_match('/\€\s[0-9]/',$str)) {
  // echo'has € digit';
  $currency = '€';
} else if (preg_match('/\€[0-9]/',$str)) {
  // echo'has €digit';
  $currency = '€';
}
```

Comment: You want `10` or `10,00` in output?

Comment: he said digit, so maybe just the 1

Comment: I want 10,00 if there is use , in digit

Comment: as a side note, consider the `?` quantifier in `\s?`

Comment: you can even capture the currency in another group! `/([$€£])\s?([0-9])/`

Comment: [Something like this](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/8lA) would work with 0+ spaces after the $ and either , or . as delimiter.

Comment: @scrowler I tried to add group but not work  \([$€£])(?:\s*?)([\d,.]+) am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (preg_match('/\$\D*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)/', $input, $matches)) {
   echo $matches[1] . "\n"; // 10,00
}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dL7oK9/1)

Comment: I tried to add group like this '/\([$£€])\D*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)/' am i doing something wrong??

Comment: [This should work too](http://regex101.com/r/dL7oK9/2), just make sure to use matched group #2 now i.e. `$matches[2]`

Answer (score 1):

Capture it:

```
if (preg_match('/\$\s([0-9])/',$str, $matches)) {
                     ^-----^       ^^^^^^^^^^
   $digit = $matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to use php regular expression

```
$str = '$10.00';
preg_match('/\d+(,|.)?\d+/',$str,$matches);


print_r($matches);
```

You may want to test as well. Just in case I have command (,) and dot (.) because you have $,€,£ signs and amounts may be represented differently with dot or comma.

If you want to test it you can use the following link http://leaverou.github.io/regexplained/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(preg_match('/([£$€])([0-9]+[.,]?(?:[0-9]{2})?)/', $str, $matches)) {
    $currency = $matches[1];
    $value = $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Example.
You can use substr and strrchr.

> $string = '$ 10,00';
>
> $return = substr(strrchr($string, '$'), 1);
>
> echo $return; //10,00